# 301 Redirect with correct slug

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

**Redirect all changed/duplicate urls**

```
/changed-title/2
/another-changed-title/2
```

**To  correct url**

```
/original-correct-title/2
```

**For example**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232323/original-title-of-question
```

**If I change the last part of url (slug) and hit enter**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232323/changed-title-of-question-duplicate
```

**still gets redirected to correct url with correct slug**

Try it on the current page

I want to do the same thing

I am using symfony framework

**routing.yml**

```
topic_item_redirect:
    path:   /topic/{title}/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Topic:redirectToItem }

topic_item:
    path:    /topic/{title}/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Topic:item }
```

**TopicController.php**

```
public function redirectToItemAction($title,$id) {

    $title = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()
        ->fetchColumn(
                'select title from topic where id = ?',
                [$id]);

    // action which renders topic
    return $this->redirectToRoute('topic_item',['title'=>$title,'id'=>$id],301);
}
```

This approach not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simulate SO behavior you can add this kind of php snippet in `TopicController.php`:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$title = $_GET['title'];

$dbTitle = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()
    ->fetchColumn(
            'select title from topic where id = ?',
            [$id]);

if ($title != $dbTitle) {
   // redirect with 301 to correct /questions/<id>/<title> page
   header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: /questions/' . $id . '/' . $dbTitle);
   exit;
}
// rest of your script
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both `topic_item_redirect` and `topic_item` use the same `path` attribute, you will most certainly get redirected every time.

I think you will need to handle this in your controller: Get the slug, query the `DB` and decide whether you need/need not to redirect.

Hope this helps