# How to get identifier of an event target element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, identifier

I need to store event target elements in db/localstorage, on reload I need to update their properties based on changes. For example: There is red color text originally, but on click, need to change its property to blue color. On reload, blue color should replace the red color from Javascript (jQuery). The issue is, we can't guarantee if the element has id attribute. How can we store element unique identifier in db and later use it for updates?

```
$("body *").click(function (evt) {
    console.log($(this), 'this');
    console.log($(evt.target), 'evt target', $(evt.target)[0]);
    $(evt.target).css('color', 'blue');
    //storing event.target in local storage here. with changed property
}

$("body").ready(function() {
    //retrieve elements from db.
});
```

Comment: `evt.target.id` would suffice

Comment: We cannot guarantee if all elements has "id" attribute

Comment: So you want a unique identifier to an element that may or may not have a unique identifier?

Comment: What properties/attribute will be unique and guaranteed?

Comment: _"How can we store element unique identifier in db and later use it for updates"_. If the element doesn't have an id, then by definition you can't store the id. Surely this is trivially obvious. Either give all the elements ids, or find some other combination of things by which to reliably uniquely identify it (e.g. CSS properties, position in DOM, or something.).

Comment: Actually the requirement is to build for all possible cases. The program should work on any page (Any client who uses our SDK).

Comment: This sounds like a line in your docs - "To use our cool SDK, all of your elements must be uniquely identifiable...."

Comment: @Jamiec Or "Our cool SDK only works on uniquely identifiable elements". :D

Comment: Related (if not complete duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226689/unique-element-id-even-if-element-doesnt-have-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this using https://github.com/fczbkk/css-selector-generator

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is, we can't guarantee if the element has id attribute.
>
> The program should work on any page (Any client who uses our SDK).

No. Simply you cannot. The only way you can identify the element is with ID or some sort of unique/group identifier. If you cannot guarantee them, there is no way you can recognise them.